# func shuffleArray Xcode 8.3 как сменять массив

Tags: swift

```
     func scrollView() { // запуск таймером ...

 /***        func shuffleArray(_ array: [String]) -> [String] { // рабочая в Xcode 8.3...
         //но выдает сдвоенные изображения...

         var newArray = array
         for index in 0...array.count - 1 { //
         let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray_0.count - 1))
         let randomIndex = Int(randomNumber)
         newArray[randomIndex] = array[index]
         } // bracket for
         return newArray
         } // bracket shuffle

            var result = shuffleArray(myArray_0) // var result передается для 
            // работы scrollView с параметром (myArray_0)
            print(result)  ***/

      // нужно менять массвы 
      // var myArray_ 0 = ["proba_0.png"]
      // var myArray_1 = ["proba_1.png"]

      func shuffleArray(_ array: [String]) -> [String] { 
            var newArray = array


            for index in 0...array.count - 1 { //

                var whatArray_0 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2))) // генератор выбора массива
                print("whatArray_0");
                if (whatArray_0 == 0) { // mork_1
                print("whatArray==0");
                var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray_0.count-1))
                let randomIndex = Int(randomNumber)
                newArray[randomIndex] = array[index]
            } // if == 0

                if (whatArray_0 == 1) { // ring_1
                    print("whatArray==1");
                    var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray_1.count-1))
                    let randomIndex = Int(randomNumber)
                    newArray[randomIndex] = array[index]
                } // if == 1

            } // for
            return newArray
        } // shuffle

        var result = shuffleArray(myArray_0) // передается в scrollView...
        print(result); // result выводится...
        print("result = OK"); // result = OK выводится

// запускается без ОШ, но в result выдает только значение myArray_0...  
// при любых значениях var whatArray_0 = ...поскольку так и указано в строке   
//  var result = ...и компилятор принимает только это...  

как можно это устранить = ?
пробовал передать параметр newArray (var result = shuffleArray(newArray) ? 
но локальную снаружи не признают...

    } // bracket func scrollView

func scrollView() {  
var myArray_0 = ["mork_1.png", "mork_2.png", "mork_3.png"]  
var myArray_1 = ["ring_1.png", "ring_2.png", "ring_3.png"]  
var myArray_2 = ["ball_1_1.png", "ball_2_1.png", "ball_1_1.png"]  
 var whatArray = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2))) // генератор выбора массива  
 if whatArray == 0 { print("выбран массив myArray_0")}  
 if whatArray == 1 { print("выбран массив myArray_1")}  
 if whatArray == 2 { print("выбран массив myArray_2")}  
 else {print("else")}  
    // далее нужно чтобы func shuffleArray обработала  только один из  массивов
    // и выдала этот массив  в let result ...
```

Comment: Если вам нужен ответ, желательно переписать код, сделав его хоть немного читабильнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:

```
func scrollView() {
var myArray = [["mork_1.png", "mork_2.png", "mork_3.png"],
                 ["ring_1.png", "ring_2.png", "ring_3.png"],
                 ["ball_1_1.png", "ball_2_1.png", "ball_1_1.png"]]

func shuffleArray(_ array: [String]) -> [String] {
    var check = true
    var count = 0
    var countArray = [Int]()
    var newArray = Array(repeating: "", count: array.count)

    while check {
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
        if !countArray.contains(randomNumber) {
            countArray.append(randomNumber)
            count += 1
            check = (count != array.count)
        }
    }
    for i in 0..<array.count {
        newArray[i] = array[countArray[i]]
    }

    return newArray
}
let numberArray = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray.count)))
let result = shuffleArray(myArray[numberArray])
print(result)}
```

Comment: функция при выводе содержимого массива меняет порядок индексации и выдает результат пермешивания для последующего использования (scrollView)... затененный код - это вариант нормально работающей функции...пробовал через генератор и применение ветвления IF получить на выходе то же самое, но с другим массивом при каждом запуске...var result не берет ничего из IF..вообще пробовал .разные варианты в том числе и в разных местах и в том числе и через switch - case, но ни как...запутался...@Oleg Soloviev

Comment: Посмотрите как отрабатывает random (выведите через print), увидите в чем проблема. Возможно это поможет.

Comment: print(randomNumber) // дает какое-то одно из значений индекса массива (myArray_0)

Comment: print(randomIndex) // дает то, что ему передано через randomNumber;  а вот print(newArray) // выдает весь массив из var randomNumber (myArray_0 в String формате),что и нужно...;т.е.IF что ему написали, то IF и сделал...функция делает return newArray, чем все и завершается...проблема в том . чтобы как-то запихнуть return newArray в выходные параметры функции т.е в var result = shuffleArray(newArray)...для дальнейшей работы:сразу компилятор дает ОШ = 267:35: Use of unresolved identifier 'newArray'@Oleg Soloview

Comment: Непонятно. Лучше напишите пример массива (array[1,2,3...]) и что должно получиться в результате работы функции. Т.е. пример входных данных - пример выходных данных.

Comment: для отладки два  массива (в плане больше)  myArray_0 = ["mork_1.png", "mork_2.png", "mork_3.png", "mork_4.png", "mork_5.png"] и myArray_1 = ["ring_1.png", "ring_2.png", "ring_3.png", "ring_4.png", "ring_5.png",];нужно чтобы func shuffleArray при запуске брала один из них, (в зависимости от значения генератора случайных чисел var whatArray_0; функция при выводе содержимого массива меняет порядок индексации и выдает результат пермешивания для последующего использования (в scrollView из  var result = ...)

Comment: в простом случае на выходе var result имеет значение 
print(result) выдает ["mork_1.png", "mork_5.png", "mork_3.png", "mork_4.png", "mork_5.png"] т.е. в scrollView выдается массив String и дальше по расписанию...@Oleg Soloviev

Comment: Написал update в ответе.

Comment: func scrollView() {

Comment: добавил то, что нужно в конец вопроса - в комментарии не помещается и совсем не форматируется ... может что получится...проблема что func shuffleArray никак не хочет выдать как параметр другой массив...update делает то же что было и раньше...с одним массивом все нормально...@Oleg Soloview

Comment: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2))) будет выдавать только 0 или 1, при этом, т.к. диапазон маленький, какая-то из цифр (0 или 1) будет намного чаще другой, поэтому кажется, что выдается только один массив.

Comment: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2))) - просто забыл поменять на 4 при написании для примера в комментарии...@Oleg Soloviev

Comment: См. update. Запустите scrollView раз десять, увидите, что массив меняется.

Comment: это = ОК...хотел имена массивов использовать дальше для других целей...буду думать как это сделать в этом варианте...спс...@Oleg Soloview

Comment: 08sept2018 = сделал print() каждого оператора, но так и не нашел где func shuttleArray берет именно номер массива (не элемент массива...)... = ?  @Oleg Soloviev

Comment: shuffleArray(myArray[N])

Comment: print(shuffleArray(myArray[N])) --- выдает массив в формате String---print(result)--- выдает массив в формате String --- но если сделать if (result == shuffleArray(myArray[N])) --- то блок  if не хочет это признавать ... пробовал многие параметры и варианты для if, но определение выполнения условий нет... нужно через ветвление по if определять какой массив пошел в работу ... [0], [1], [2] ...@Oleg Soloviev

Comment: См. update. Номер массива numberArray